# List of sensors in Moto 360

Tags: wear-os, android-sensors, moto-360

I can't seem to find any complete information on which sensors actually are built into the Motorola Moto360. Where or how can I find out about it? There's no documentation about it from Motorola, is that common practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also searching for an official list but you can list them as stated in Google sensors overview:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

you can log them as the following example:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;

mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
final List<Sensor> deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
for(Sensor type : deviceSensors){
    Log.e("sensors",type.getStringType());
}
```

android.sensor.accelerometer

android.sensor.step_counter

android.sensor.wrist_tilt_gesture

android.sensor.gyroscope

android.sensor.magnetic_field

android.sensor.light

android.sensor.rotation_vector

android.sensor.orientation

android.sensor.gravity

android.sensor.linear_acceleration

android.sensor.significant_motion

You can also check how to use them in here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

and on the subsequent pages regarding the sensors.